# Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

Tags: jenkins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxpfM.jpg)
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes

> C:\Program Files\Automation\Git\bin\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
>   ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

Answer (score 0):

1.it seems your Jenkins server is not able to clone your git repository.
2.you need to make sure correct authentication is setup between your Jenkins and Git remote server.
It might be ssh or credentials.